# What's the most intuitive way to organize a set of endpoints to fetch users and their roles in groups?

Tags: api-design, rpc, protobuf, user-group

What's the most intuitive way to organize a set of endpoints to fetch users and their roles in groups? i.e.

- Users and their roles in a specified group.
- Groups a user is in, and their role in each group.

### Attempt 1

We began with the following:

```
message UserWithRole {
  User user = 1;
  Role role = 2;
}

message GetUsersInGroupRequest {
  string group_id = 1;
}

message GetUsersInGroupResponse {
  repeated UserWithRole users = 1;
}

rpc getUsersInGroup (GetUsersInGroupRequest) returns (GetUsersInGroupResponse)
```

And for the flip side (groups a user belongs to):

```
message GroupWithRole {
  Group group = 1;
  Role role = 2;
}

message GetGroupsForUserRequest {
  string user_id = 1;
}

message GetGroupsForUserResponse {
  repeated GroupWithRole groups = 1;
}

rpc getGroupsForUser (GetGroupsForUserRequest) returns (GetGroupsForUserResponse)
```

This felt awkward and unnecessarily verbose.

### Attempt 2

So, what about a using a single model?

```
message UserGroupMapping {
  User user = 1;
  Group group = 2;
  Role role = 3;
}

message GetUsersInGroupRequest {
  string group_id = 1;
}

message GetUsersInGroupResponse {
  repeated UserGroupMapping user_group_mappings = 1;
}

rpc getUsersInGroup (GetUsersInGroupRequest) returns (GetUsersInGroupResponse)

message GetGroupsForUserRequest {
  string user_id = 1;
}

message GetGroupsForUserResponse {
  repeated UserGroupMapping user_group_mappings = 1;
}

rpc getGroupsForUser (GetGroupsForUserRequest) returns (GetGroupsForUserResponse)
```

This appeals because the same model can be used for other endpoints that return both a user and group:

```
rpc getUserAndPrimaryGroup (string user_id) returns (UserGroupMapping);
```

Let's even say we consolidate the above like this:

### Attempt 2b

```
message UserGroupMapping {
  User user = 1;
  Group group = 2;
  Role role = 3;
}

message GetUserGroupMappingsRequest {
  enum IdType {
    USER_ID = 0;
    GROUP_ID = 1;
  }
  IdType id_type = 1;
  string id = 2;
}

message GetUserGroupMappingsResponse {
  repeated UserGroupMapping user_group_mappings = 1;
}

rpc getUserGroupMappings (GetUserGroupMappingsRequest) returns (GetUserGroupMappingsResponse)
```

But **either way**, the problem is that one of the dimensions, `User` or `Group` is always needlessly repeated despite being the uniform for any given request, _i.e. if you're getting a user's groups, there's no need to repeat `User` again and again, but here we are.

### Summary

I know either way "works," but since this will be a very central microservice (used by other microservices managing resources, payments, auditing, etc.) I want to design the API right from the start.

Meanwhile I'll continue searching the web for <kbd>protobuf</kbd> <kbd>user</kbd> <kbd>group</kbd> <kbd>management</kbd> <kbd>api</kbd> <kbd>design</kbd> <kbd>examples</kbd> etc. but just getting a lot of irrelevant results.

Comment: What is your problem with the inclusion of `User`/`Group` in attempt 2? Is it aesthetics, message size, something else?

Comment: I guess it feels "wrong" that an endpoint should return User A / Group 1, User A / Group 5, User A / Group 6, User A / Group 7, etc. where each "User A" includes all the user's details: id, f_name, l_name, email, timezone, etc.